# Как сделать данную задачу в функциональном стиле?

Tags: функциональное-программирование, f#

Мне нужно сделать замену каждого n-ого повторения символа в строке на определенный символ.
Например, пусть n = 3, символ замены - '#', тогда строка подобного вида: "aaabcccbbcccbbb" превратится в такое: "aa#bcc#b#cc#bb#". Как решить эту задачу в функциональном стиле на языке F#?
Вот пример функции, сделанной в императивном стиле:

```
public static string Swap(string word, int n, char swapelem)
        {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            char[] letters = new char[256];
            foreach (var c in word)
            {
                letters[c]++;
                str.Append((letters[c] % n == 0) ? swapelem: c);
            }
            return str.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Покажите вашу попытку решения.

Comment: _в функциональном стиле_ - напишите функцию, которая принимает значения и возвращает _новое_ значение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм такой

- Индексируем элементы

```
123456789abcdef
aaabcccbbcccbbb
```

- Упорядочиваем по значению устойчивой сортировкой

```
123489def567abc
aaabbbbbbcccccc
```

- Группируем

```
123 489def 567abc
aaa bbbbbb cccccc
```

- Заменяем каждый n-ный элемент группы

```
123 489def 567abc
aa# bb#bb# cc#cc#
```

- Сливаем и упорядочиваем по индексу

```
123456789abcdef
aa#bcc#b#cc#bb#
```

- Отбрасываем индексы

```
aa#bcc#b#cc#bb#
```

Comment: Для F# или, например, Scala, второй пункт не нужен.